# How to reinstall windows 10 microsoft store after complete uninstall using powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I have removed microsoft store using powershell.
I have looked on the internet for solutions found this command `Get-AppxPackage -allusers Microsoft.WindowsStore | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register ?$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml?}`
but it doesnt work as it does nothing. I tried installing appx file from adguard store but it is stuck at 10 percent. I tried windows 10 trouble shooter and system repair both doesnt help. so what should I do

Answer (score 0):

Silly now I have been stuck for two days and now I have found the answer
this command `Get-AppxPackage -allusers | foreach {Add-AppxPackage -register “$($_.InstallLocation)\appxmanifest.xml” -DisableDevelopmentMode}` didnt work because my app installer wasnt working I had to reset it and after that the command worked which installed most apps but without microsoft store, but now the appx file from adguard worked and the problem was fixed